# scanForPeripheralsWithServices with nil argument not discovering

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

In my iOS app using core bluetooth, I'm try to scan for all peripherals. Before this, I used to scan for a certain service. I am using the code below.

```
    centralManager!.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
    //centralManager!.scanForPeripheralsWithServices([BLEUUIDS.Status.Service], options: nil)
```

What is odd is when the first line is used with nil for the services arg, `didDiscoverPeripheral` is never called. When I comment that line and uncomment the line below it, `didDiscoverPeripheral` is called. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Are you scanning in the foreground our background? . Try the light blue app from the app see if it can discover your peripheral.

Comment: Thanks for writing. I'm scanning in the foreground. lightblue can discover the peripheral but I'm at a total loss as to why passing nil would prevent me from discovering.

Comment: Then can you show more code?  Where do you initiate scanning?

Comment: Absolutely. Scanning is started shortly after the app is started.  I have a gist here. https://gist.github.com/foobar8675/f793ecd350283d90a3eb . The fact that it works with passing in a value for the services to scan for and does not work without that is what baffles me. I have this same code in a test project and it seems to work fine there. In the debugger, I've verified power is on.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for commenting Paulw11. I found the problem was I was initiating and powering up my central as the first thing the app did. (if u can see below) . I moved the initialization to within `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and am able to scan without a filter on services. I'm pretty sure this is an apple bug and plan to file a radar (one of many) once I have some time.

```
var centralManager = BLECentralManager.sharedInstance

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {        
    return true
}
```

}

(as an aside, I actually did some work on the LightBlue app. I'm glad to see people are using it)